# How can I set a root directory dynamically?

Tags: python

I am trying to generate an exe for my desktop application. I am working in both English and Arabic language using freeserif font. When, I have tried to install my freeserif font like this -

```
inv_file = FPDF()
inv_file.add_page()
inv_file.set_xy(0, 0)
inv_file.add_font("monaco", "", os.path.join(gv.install_path,"FreeSerif.ttf"), uni=True)
```

It works perfectly into my desktop. But after generating an exe, it will give me a error message into my log that no search file in directory. I have generated a custom log file to see what the problem is. I have seen that whenever the system call `os.path.join` it's trying to access my local machines directory instead of client's setup directory. I have shared the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqnQY.jpg) of the log file for better understanding.
I have also shared my setup_path code -

```
gv.application_dir = "application"
gv.install_dir = os.path.join("application", "install") 
gv.modules_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules")
gv.fi_dir = os.path.join("application", "icons")
gv.itemmanage_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "itemmanage")
gv.assets_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "itemmanage", "assets")
gv.image_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "itemmanage", "assets", "images")
gv.user_image_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "itemmanage", "assets", "images", "user")
gv.depend_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "dependancy")
gv.depend_image_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "dependancy", "images")
gv.invoice_dir = os.path.join("application", "modules", "invoices")
```

Comment: It doesn't have any clue about your home system's paths unless you put it in the code.  `os.path.join("application", "install")` produces `"application/install"`.  That's all.  If the files are located relative to your script, then you should build a path based on `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `__file__`.

In which ever script has all of your file path assignments (so long as the file paths are in fact relative to that script):

Using `os`:

```py
import os

root = os.path.dirname(__file__)
gv.application_dir = os.path.join(root, "application")
gv.install_dir = os.path.join(gv.application_dir, "install")
...
```

Using `pathlib`:

```py
from pathlib import Path

root = Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
gv.application_dir = root / 'application'
gv.install_dir = gv.application_dir / 'install'
...
```